# Как получить доступ к TextArea из другого окна?

Tags: javafx

Есть главное окно Main, где есть TextArea и есть второе окно, где есть Tableview. Мне нужно получить текст из TextArea и передать в Tableview, то есть мне нужно получить доступ к элементу TextArea из другого окна. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получи ссылку на нужный контроллер куда ты собираешься писать данные, в этом контроллере должен быть метод который их будет принимать.

Вот так получать контроллер:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
Pane p = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("foo.fxml").openStream());
FooController fooController = (FooController) fxmlLoader.getController();
```

Comment: Этот код где писать в классе Main окна или в контроллере этого окна? И какой метод написать, что бы принимал?

Comment: @АнтонЛяли этот код писать там где у тебя textArea.А какой код писать чтобы принимал значение, это уже другой вопрос) всё зависит от твоего tableview, без просмотра всего кода ничего не скажу

Comment: Поясню. Два окна, один главный, где находится TextArea, второй - побочный, где находится TableView. Есть еще класс Filter, куда нужно передать текст из первого окна. По идее, мне нужно только получить текст из главного окна.

Comment: Ну исходя из вопроса, тебе нужно в классе Filter получить ссылку на контроллер окна где у тебя textArea, и в этом контроллере ты должен получить свой текст

Comment: А как мне получить ссылку на контроллер окна?

Comment: Это есть в ответе). Ты должен загрузить fxml(если ты их конечно используешь), и достать из него контроллер

Comment: Использую=) Так и не смог получить доступ к элементу, решил проблему другим методом